# Rsync shows files are synced but could not find it in AWS S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, capistrano3

I am using **capistrano 3** and **Ruby on Rails 3.2.14**, with **Ruby 2.1.0**. I have written a **recipe** to check for S3 mount status and then run specific set of actions:

1. If bucket is unmounted and the folder`(public/system)` is empty then mount it using `s3fs`
2. If bucket is unmounted and the folder is not empty then use rsync to move the files from `public/system` to s3 bucket and then emptying the folder `public/system` and remounting it.

**rsync** shows that the files are incrementally sent but I cannot find them in the bucket. This is the output that I get:

```
  05 rsync -av /home/deploy/unmounted /home/deploy/mounted
  05 sending incremental file list
  05 unmounted/
  05 unmounted/ckeditor/
  05 unmounted/ckeditor/pictures/
  05 unmounted/ckeditor/pictures/16736/
  05 unmounted/ckeditor/pictures/16736/bike.jpg
  05 unmounted/ckeditor/pictures/16736/content_bike.jpg
  05 unmounted/ckeditor/pictures/16736/thumb_bike.jpg
  05
  05 sent 750,943 bytes  received 93 bytes  166,896.89 bytes/sec
  05 total size is 750,396  speedup is 1.00
```

**Recipe** for mounting s3, I have not optimized it yet as first I just want to check if its working,

```
desc "Mounting S3"
    task :mounting_s3 do
        on main_server, in: :sequence, wait: 5 do |host|
            as 'deploy' do
                within "#{code_folder_path}/current" do
                    code_folder = "#{code_folder_path}/current"
                    path = "#{code_folder_path}/current/public/system"
                    unmount_path = "#{code_folder_path}/shared/public/system"

                    # check first if public/system exists
                    puts "** Checking if public/system folder exists on #{host}"
                    puts "** testing if it is there #{test("[ -d #{path} ]")}"
                    if test("[ -d #{path} ]")
                        puts "** public/system folder exists.."
                        puts "** Checking if S3 is mounted"
                        result = capture "cd #{code_folder} && mountpoint public/system" , raise_on_non_zero_exit: false
                        puts "result #{result}"
                        if  result.match('is a mountpoint') != nil
                            puts "** S3 is mounted at #{path} on #{host}"
                        elsif result.match('is not a mountpoint') != nil
                            puts "** #{path} is not a mountpoint on #{host}"
                            result = capture "ls -A #{unmount_path}"
                            if result.length > 0
                                puts "** public/system is not empty"
                                if test("[ -d /home/deploy/mounted ]")

                                    puts "** mounted folder exists"

                                    puts "checking if folder is mounted"
                                    result = capture "mountpoint /home/deploy/mounted" , raise_on_non_zero_exit: false
                                    puts "result #{result}"

                                    if  result.match('is a mountpoint') != nil
                                        puts "** mounted folder is mounted so unmounting it"
                                        execute! "fusermount -u /home/deploy/mounted"
                                        puts "** mounted folder is unmounted now"

                                        puts "** Deleting mounted folder"
                                        execute! "cd /home/deploy/ && sudo rm -r mounted"
                                        puts "** mounted folder deleted"

                                    elsif result.match('is not a mountpoint') != nil

                                        puts "** Deleting mounted folder"
                                        execute! "sudo rm -r /home/deploy/mounted"
                                        puts "** mounted folder deleted"

                                    end
                                end

                                if test("[ -d /home/deploy/unmounted ]")
                                    puts "** deleting unmounted folder"
                                    execute! "cd /home/deploy/ && sudo rm -r unmounted"
                                    puts "** unmounted folder deleted"
                                end

                                puts "** mounting bucket"
                                execute! "cd /home/deploy/ && mkdir unmounted && mkdir mounted"
                                execute! "s3fs s3_bucket /home/deploy/mounted"
                                puts "** bucket mounted on /home/deploy/mounted folder"

                                puts "** copying files from public/system to unmounted"
                                execute! "cp -r #{unmount_path}/* /home/deploy/unmounted/."
                                puts "** files copied"

                                puts "** syncing unmounted files to s3"
                                execute! "rsync -av /home/deploy/unmounted /home/deploy/mounted"
                                puts "** Files synced"

                                puts "** unmounting mounted folder now for safety"
                                execute! "fusermount -u /home/deploy/mounted"
                                puts "** folder unmounted"

                                puts "** deleting unmounted folder now"
                                execute! "sudo rm -r /home/deploy/unmounted"
                                puts "** folders deleted\n"

                                puts "** emptying public/system"
                                execute! "sudo rm -r #{unmount_path}/../system/*"
                                puts "** folder is empty, mounting public/system"

                                execute! "s3fs s3-bucket #{path}"
                                puts "** s3 is mounted"
                            else
                                puts "** public/system is empty"
                                execute! "cd #{code_folder} && s3fs s3-bucket #{path}"
                                puts "** s3 is mounted"
                            end 

                        end 
                    else
                        puts "** public/system folder does not exists.."
                        puts "** Mounting S3"
                        execute! "cd #{code_folder} && s3fs s3-bucket #{path}"
                    end 
                end
            end
```

The output that I get after running `cap staging deploy:mounting_s3 --trace`:

```
** Invoke www_data (first_time)
** Execute www_data
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke rvm:hook (first_time)
** Execute rvm:hook
** Invoke rvm:check (first_time)
** Execute rvm:check
rvm 1.27.0 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
ruby-2.1.0
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-linux]
** Invoke bundler:map_bins (first_time)
** Execute bundler:map_bins
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_rails_env
** Invoke deploy:set_linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_linked_dirs
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env 
** Invoke deploy:mounting_s3 (first_time)
** Execute deploy:mounting_s3
** Checking if public/system folder exists on webby
** testing if it is there true
** public/system folder exists..
** Checking if S3 is mounted
result public/system is not a mountpoint
** /home/deploy/apps/web_cc_cap1/current/public/system is not a mountpoint on webby
** public/system is not empty
** mounted folder exists
checking if folder is mounted
result /home/deploy/mounted is not a mountpoint
** Deleting mounted folder
00:00 deploy:mounting_s3
      01 sudo rm -r /home/deploy/mounted
    ✔ 01 webby 0.649s
** mounted folder deleted
** mounting bucket
      02 cd /home/deploy/ && mkdir unmounted && mkdir mounted
    ✔ 02 webby 0.631s
      03 s3fs s3-bucket /home/deploy/mounted
    ✔ 03 webby 0.619s
** bucket mounted on /home/deploy/mounted folder
** copying files from public/system to unmounted
      04 cp -r /home/deploy/apps/web_cc_cap1/shared/public/system/* /home/deploy/unmounted/.
    ✔ 04 webby 0.651s
** files copied
** syncing unmounted files to s3
      05 rsync -av /home/deploy/unmounted /home/deploy/mounted
      05 sending incremental file list
      05 unmounted/
      05 unmounted/ckeditor/
      05 unmounted/ckeditor/pictures/
      05 unmounted/ckeditor/pictures/16736/
      05 unmounted/ckeditor/pictures/16736/bike.jpg
      05 unmounted/ckeditor/pictures/16736/content_bike.jpg
      05 unmounted/ckeditor/pictures/16736/thumb_bike.jpg
      05
      05 sent 750,943 bytes  received 93 bytes  166,896.89 bytes/sec
      05 total size is 750,396  speedup is 1.00
    ✔ 05 webby 4.299s
** Files synced
** unmounting mounted folder now for safety
      06 fusermount -u /home/deploy/mounted
    ✔ 06 webby 0.631s
** folder unmounted
** deleting unmounted folder now
      07 sudo rm -r /home/deploy/unmounted
    ✔ 07 webby 0.621s
** folders deleted
** emptying public/system
      08 sudo rm -r /home/deploy/apps/web_cc_cap1/shared/public/system/../system/*
    ✔ 08 webby 0.649s
** folder is empty, mounting public/system
      09 s3fs s3-bucket /home/deploy/apps/web_cc_cap1/current/public/system
    ✔ 09 webby 0.623s
** s3 is mounted
```

Why is it not sending the files to s3 bucket?

Comment: Try `rsync -avvv /home/deploy/unmounted /home/deploy/mounted`. You will get a very verbose log. Probably it will tell you something.

Comment: Thanks @fossil, I was actually doing a mistake, my intent was to copy the contents of unmounted folder and not the folder itself. So I fixed the rsync code: `rsync -av /home/deploy/unmounted/* /home/deploy/mounted` and it worked as expected.

Comment: Guessed so. `rsync -av` pretty much does what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually doing a mistake, my intent was to copy the contents of **unmounted** folder and **not the folder** itself. So I fixed the rsync code: `rsync -av /home/deploy/unmounted/* /home/deploy/mounted` and it worked as expected.